# DocumentDB, use small field names for JSON documents to minimize length

Tags: json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

In DocumentDB we are limited to 512KB JSON document.

Looking to the answer [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/86), to estimate the size of the document sent it is recommended to use the following method `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` and `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)`. There is no notion of compression even with the .NET SDK.

If you are using an array of custom objects, the field names could be repeated a lot.

My question is: should I try use short name for JSON fields to reduce size over readability? Do you recommend to override serialized property name with  `[JsonProperty]` attribute provided by JSON.NET?

Comment: It's really up to you - lots of ways to compress/minify JSON (several libraries exist which do this), including your suggestion of using shorter property names.  No single right answer to this (and tool / framework recommendation questions are off-topic). Just curious (and not directly related to the question) - have you confirmed that your documents require > 512K?

Comment: Agree with David. And, I've found that any data modeling that puts you close to 512K is probably overly denormalized. It's critical that you never decide on a data model where an array element or sub-object can grow unbounded. If you are thinking of forcing a limit to the number of elements in an array field or sub-object and there is no natural limit (a car only has 4 tires), that's a warning sign.

Comment: @DavidMakogon yes I had a situation, especially with arrays where the number of items makes the document size larger than 512KB

Comment: Unbounded arrays (which typically lead to large documents) are not a good thing. No matter what the max size, there is always a limit.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone Actually, I am in the situation of an array containing an unbounded number of elements. I created a service that chunks this array in multiple documents.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I agree with you, you cannot create unbounded arrays in a document (no matter what the document size limit is). However, in some situation you can win a lot of space and augment the size of the chunks just by reducing the length of property names, right?

Comment: Why can't you make each element of your array be a separate document? You'll have to do two round trips to get the parent and children, but that's what a join in an SQL database does automatically so that's not an efficiency of execution issue and it's only a minor increase to your program, I suspect less than the chunking algorithm that you implemented.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone What you are saying is really interesting, I tried to minimize the amount of different documents created and now I do not know really why... In my situation the length of the array is large while the contained objects are small. More generally, I am just starting to see all the potential of a document oriented NoSQL database. At first, I saw DocDB as a persistent JSON to POCO object mapper, maybe the .NET SDK was pushing me a little in this vision. I did not see all the querying potential. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: If I add my latest comment as an answer, would you accept it?

Comment: Yes sure, but I think we should try to tie the answer closely to the original question even if this one is a little naïve and vague, if we want it to be useful for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer from all the comments:

@DavidMakogon "It's really up to you - lots of ways to compress/minify JSON (several libraries exist which do this), including your suggestion of using shorter property names."

I agree with David. I would add that shrinking the field names is going to have a negative impact on the readability/debugability of your system.

On the other hand, I've found that any data modeling that puts you close to 512K is probably overly denormalized. It's critical that you never decide on a data model where an array element or sub-object can grow unbounded. If you are thinking of forcing a limit to the number of elements in an array field or sub-object and there is no natural limit (a car only has 4 tires), that's a warning sign.

In the comments, you indicate that the array would grow unbounded. So, my recommendation would be to change your data model so each element of your array is a separate document. You'll have to do two round trips to get the parent and children, but that's what a join in an SQL database does automatically so that's not an efficiency of execution issue and it's only a minor increase to your program, I suspect less than the chunking algorithm you say that you implemented in the comments.